# CKEditor configs in Form.io?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, formio

Does anyone know how to edit configs are for the CKeditor of the HTML content editor in Form.io are to enable code editing? I have searched the code and can't find where they are.

Comment: I have the same issue. I'm trying to change the config options for ckeditor in form.io. Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Hi Lane. No I have not! While I find Forom.io great, but I find it really difficult to get answers to questions like this, which would be seem to be a simple config hidden somewhere. I will definitely let you know if I ever find an answer on this...